# sending an email as part of a bash shell script

Tags: bash, email, automation

I have herd of examples of people using alpine to send emails based on data collected or generated from bash scripts.

I have been looking for tutorials to create this for myself with no success. I do have alpine talking to my email server, but requires me to still enter a password. I am guessing I will need to correct this as well.

My end result would be to run a long task such as do a time lapse on my Pi3, and send an email... perform some imagemagick work, render a video on my servers gpu, send an email... it would be easier for me to check emails looking for machines reporting in completion of tasks, sending logs as well for review etc... I got all of this set except the darn email.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to send mail in bash one-liner via smtp public service using "nail" mail-client:

```
echo 'Test mail body text' | env MAILRC=/dev/null from='a@a.ru' smtp=mail.a.ru smtp-auth-user='a' smtp-auth-password='xxx' smtp-auth=login mailx -v -n -s 'Test mail again v01' b@b.ru
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using mutt

To install in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install mutt
```

To send an email with attachment

```
echo "Please find the file attached." | mutt -a somefile.ext -s "Important File"
```